# Been asked to sign a receipt for Chocolate at Duty Free, what was it about?

Tags: europe, duty-free

It happened a week ago at Duty Free in Frankfurt airport. I just bought a box of chocolate and when I was paying for it the cashier asked me for my boarding pass and my passport (which I know is normal) and then asked me if I was from the city I was flying to from Frankfurt (which is outside of Germany). I said "yes" and then the cashier asked me to sign his copy of the receipt with the name of the city, in either language (he asked the guy before me to do the same).

Anyone know what was that about?

Comment: Just guessing here. Could be be a hobby a hobby of the cashier or it's for marketing/statistics purposes. I've seen both (not at FRA, though). I used to travel with a guy from Luxembourg and some immigration officers got excited about this since they were clearly "collecting" and Luxembourg is a rare one.